# Foreach not working pushing every record to promise function in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, loops, promise

```
parse().then(function (contacts) {
    contacts.forEach(cont => {
        cont.id,
            cont.first_name,
            cont.last_name,
            cont.phone_numbers,
            cont.organization_name,
            cont.email

        appoloemail = cont.email;
        fullname = cont.first_name + ' ' + cont.last_name;

        deal = cont.first_name + ' Deal';
        dealname = deal;
        orgname = cont.organization_name;
        title = cont.title;
 console.log('ORG NAME in Start:', orgname)
        console.log('Full Name: ', fullname)
        console.log('Email', appoloemail);
        console.log('Custom Time: ', newbacktime);
        console.log('Contact Update Time: ', contact_updatedate);

       create_org(orgname)
            .then(function (orgid) {
                console.log('Org Id Return:', orgid);
                globalorgid=orgid;
                console.log('In create org: ',globalorgid)
                createperson(fullname, orgid, appoloemail, apollophone)

            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Error!', err);
            })
        //  }
console.log('Loop End::');
    })

}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The loop iterates every record first and then start pushing the record and org and person but org function complete execute and push all the org data but the create_person push data which is in the last index of the array of foreach loop and every org have the same name of the person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEach()` is executed synchronously but you have asynchronous code inside (assuming `create_org` and `createperson` return promises). 
You should use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

**ES6 style**

```
parse()
.then(contacts =>
  Promise.all(contacts.map(
    cont => create_org(cont.organization_name)
    .then(orgid => createperson(`${cont.first_name} ${cont.last_name}`,
                                orgid,
                                cont.email,
                                cont.phone_numbers)
))))    
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

**ES5 style** (but not real ES5)

```
parse()
.then(function(contacts) {
  return Promise.all(contacts.map(function(cont) {
    return create_org(cont.organization_name)
    .then(function(orgid) { // This is the result of create_org()
      return createperson(cont.first_name + ' ' + cont.last_name',
                          orgid, // orgid is used here
                          cont.email,
                          cont.phone_numbers);
    });
  }));
}) 
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: but i need orgid for createperson function the create function is dependent on create_org function.

Comment: Since `create_org` returns a promise, the `then()` callback function will have orgid as parameter. I will write it in ES5 style for you to understand

Answer (score 1):

Then part of your `create_org(orgname)` will executed somewhere in time. And looks like your variables are defined with `var`, not `let`. 
So, either you define your variables inside `forEach` with `let` or just replace `forEach` with something like

```
Promise.all(contacts.map(
        contact=>create_org(contact.organization_name)
        .then(orgid=>createperson(contact.first_name+' '+conact.last_name,orgid,contact.email,contact.phone_numbers))
    )
)
```

Comment: but i need orgid for createperson function the create function is dependent on create_org function.